# Let Z a random variable with cdf: $F_Z(z)=p F_{X_1}(z)+(1-p)F_{X_2}(z)$, Find the characteristic funciton of Z

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let Z a random variable with cdf: $F_Z(z)=p F_{X_1}(z)+(1-p)F_{X_2}(z)$,

where  $F_{X_1}$ and $F_{X_2}$ are de cdf's of $X_1$ and $X_2$, and $p\in(0,1)$.

Find the characteristic function of Z.

I try to do it, but I have some problems:

My first idea was find pdf oz Z. But I don't know how, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are discretes or continuous or ..., I really don't have idea ...